# while loop condtion and termination in C programming

Tags: c

I am trying to write a while loop which only runs as user input is 'F' or 'C'. However, my while loop seems doesn't work. Could you show me what is wrong with my scanf and while loop condition

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    char response;
    while (response == 'F' || response == 'C')
    {
        printf(" Please enter F or C\n");
        scanf(" %c", &response);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to initialize `response`, try this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char response;

    response = 'F';
    while (response == 'F' || response == 'C')
    {
        printf(" Please enter F or C\n");
        scanf(" %c", &response);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and you can of course do it this way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char response;

    /* since you don't check for `scanf()`'s return value, 
     * this prevents undefined behavior 
     */
    response = 'F';
    do {
        printf(" Please enter F or C\n");
        scanf(" %c", &response);
    } while (response == 'F' || response == 'C');
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This will display the warning and keep looping when you give one of the correct inputs

Comment: So you're going to give an obviously incorrect answer because he's not good at writing English?

Comment: Is it that I can't understand english? I understand that the OP want's the loop to run as long as he inputs `'F'` or `'C'` if I am wrong, then that's another thing and of course my answer is wrong and you're welcome to downvote and I will delete it, But if that's what the OP wants then this is a correct answer.

Comment: This is obviously input validation. He wants to keep looping until you enter a correct input, which is either F or C (obviously this is related to entering a temperature). When you enter an incorrect input, it should prompt you to try again.

Comment: You understand English fine. He can't write it well. With a name like Sunny Trinh, it's probably not his native language.

Comment: Why would you respond with `Please enter F or C` if that's what the user just entered?

Comment: @Barmar because you're in a loop?

Answer (score 2):

`response` is uninitialized. Your code hasn't even gotten to the `scanf()` yet. Consider changing it to a `do-while` loop.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, the program will quit out of the loop as I enter F or C. The purpose of this program is if the user input different from F or C, the program will quit

Comment: @SunnyTrinh , Try `do{...}while(response != 'F' && response != 'C');`

Answer (score 0):

Your loop runs as long as `response` *is* `'F'` or `'C'`. What you need is

```
while (response != 'F' && response != 'C')
```

Also, `response` is not initialized. Start with

```
char response = '\0';
```

Comment: @Barmar Thanks. Made change.

Answer (score 0):

There are two common ways to do a terminate-on-input loop in C:

```
do {
    ...get input...
    do_stuff();
} while (...input does not indicate exit...);
```

or

```
while (1) {
    ...get input...
    if (...input indicates exit...) break;

    do_stuff();
}
```

I think the latter might work better for your case:

```
while (1) {
    printf(" Please enter F or C\n");
    scanf(" %c", &response);

    if ('F' == response) {
         do_f();
    } else if ('C' == response) {
        do_c();
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```